# Ubuntu not booting anymore

Tags: boot

Ubuntu it’s not booting anymore on AHCI as SATA config. Once I start my laptop it just suddenly opens the BIOS, as if there was no operating system to boot. I tried changing SATA config to Intel RST but while loading Ubuntu it gives me the error ‘Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

- `Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)`
- `Check for rootdelay=…`
- `Missing modules` (cat blah blah)
- `ALERT! UUID=some low case characters and numbers`

and in the end it opens BusyBox built-in shell

```
(initramfs)
```

[image]

Help would be highly appreciated as it seems there’s no effective solution on the internet.

Comment: Any time you drop into a busybox shell it's important to get *all* the error messages.  Typically, this happens when you have failing or bad hardware, especially when you get the "UUID... is missing" error that you indicated.  Are you able to take a photo the next time this issue happens and upload it to your question?  Additionally, do you have an external boot device that you can boot to (such as the Ubuntu installer) so we can get to a live environment/session that we can run some debugging/potential-fix steps on?

Comment: @ThomasWard I edited the post adding the picture. As I said this happens when SATA is configured with Intel, otherwise it just gets back to the bios with AHCI. Anyways I currently don’t have a boot device with me. Am I forced to get it or is there any other solution maybe through this BusyBox shell or bios?